# Height 100% in CSS does not behave how I expect

Tags: html, css

I know that in CSS a container with height: 100% should adapt the height of its parent container.
However, what happens if I put an element inside a container that has only a max-height property?
In this case, my container does not appear at all. You can find my experiment in this code pen: https://codepen.io/web265p3/pen/eYMwjgd

```
<body>
   <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
         <div class="inner-inner"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

And the CSS:

```
      .outer {
         background-color: yellow;
         height: 1000px;
         width: 300px;
      }
      .inner {
         min-height: 500px;
         width: 200px;
         background-color: green;
      }
      .inner-inner {
         height: 100%;
         width: 100px;
         background-color: aqua;
      }
```

You can find a div with a class .inner-inner there that has a height of 100%.
Its contained in another element with a min-height of 500px.

I expected the .inner-inner to be 500px high, but this is not the case. Its height is 0.

Okay, so probably the height of 100% only inherits if there is a real "height" property on the parent.
And indeed, if I add a height the inner-inner becomes visible, but not as expected.
It now fills the parent completely and does not inherit the height property, ***but suddenly the min-height***!?? You can find this here: https://codepen.io/web265p3/pen/VwXJBQG

This is a counter intuitive behavior for me. Can you explain why the browser behaves so strange and inherits a min-height after my change?

Comment: Set the `display` property (e.g. `display: flex` to the outer elem). It's because your container has no content.

Answer (score 1):

The [`height: 100%`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#the-height-property) attribute's percentage is calculated based on the containing block's height. And if that containing block doesn't have a specified and fixed height, then the percentage is invalid, and behind the scense it will default back to `auto` (which if the inner has no content, it will be zero).

So, for percentage height to work on an in-flow child, the parent must have a set height.

---

In your example, just setting a display method to the outer container, and then setting height to fill parent will fix your issue, here's an [updated CodePen](https://codepen.io/Lissy93/pen/QWmXBrj?editors=1100).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 300px;
}

.inner {
  min-height: 500px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
}

.inner-inner {
  height: fill;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="inner-inner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I am not trying to find a fix - , I just want to understand why CSS behaves like it does. What does height: 100% actually mean? Does it inherit height? Or max-height? I am confused...

Comment: Ahh sorry, I totally skipped over that. I've updated my answer... But the reason is because the CSS compiler needs to know the height of the parent element in order for `height: 100%` to work, otherwise it will default back to `auto` which is what's happening in your snippet.

Comment: I understand - but after I added a height to the parent, it does not inherit this height. Then it inherits the min-height of 500px, that it didn't want to inherit before. That appears very strange to me... ??? Why does it inherit a min-height if there is a height? Its clear to me that it will inherit nothing (auto) when there is nothing to inherit...

Answer (score 0):

`max-height` in the parent element isn't a sufficient basis for a percentage height in the child. Percentage height settings *require* a `height` setting on the parent element (and if that one is a percentage value, its parent again requires a `height` setting, and so on up to the `html` element...).

Comment: I understand - but after I added a height, it does not inherit this. Then it inherits the min-height of 500px. That appears very strange to me... ???

Comment: which `height` setting did you add? Do you have the complete code including that setting seomwhere to show?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a  bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26559 (obviously still not fixed)

There are several ways to get around this. For example:

`.inner -> position: relative`

`.inner-inner -> position: absolute`

OR

`.inner -> height: 1px; min-height: 100%`